# How to limit wcf service method for a specific ip

Tags: c#, wcf

Here is my wcf service method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/CheckID/{id}")]
    public string CheckID(string id)
    {
             /*Check reuqest where it comes from */
    }
```

I want my method send response OK if it comes/is invoked from http://particularIP.com, unless response Bad request.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use IP Filter in web.config file, like :-

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="RestrictedServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <IPFilter filter="172.*.*.* 127.0.0.1" />          
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

**Edited**

Or use can ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccessCore in which you get client IP from OperationContext.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.checkaccesscore.aspx

**Edit 2**

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
    prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string ip = endpoint.Address;
```

Comment: I didn't understand how to use CheckAccessCore method, it seems it should be overrided but it doesnt't appear in my project.

Comment: You need to include "System.ServiceModel" dll in your application.

Comment: Thank you Anand, I can get the OperationContext without implemeting the CheckAccessCore method. But, it is a very complex object, where the clint ip data is held ?

Comment: Like a charm Anand. Thanks!